# Add badge and intent to QuickContactBadge with SyncAdapter

Tags: android, synchronization, contacts, badge

I have a SyncAdapter and contact syncing works fine. Only i want a nice badge added to the QuickContactBadge in the contact application. How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. 
You basically tell, in your manifest, which activity can handle contacts which are merged. When doing the merging you have chosen a mime type, use this mime type in an  for an activity you choose:

```
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/hyves">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.hyves.profile" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Then when the activity starts you can get the contact by doing:
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(getIntent().getData(), null, null, null, null);

Comment: Hi
Thanks I found this very useful, but I would like to request you if you can provide how did you set your mimeType (vnd.hyves.profile) and how to handle into your intent and ContentsResolver subclass. 
Thanks.